# Laravel Mix Error Using version() and copyDirectory()

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I am having a problem using `copyDirectory()` with `version()` on laravel mix.

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix'),

mix.copyDirectory('node_modules/bootstrap', 'public/vendor/bootstrap')
.sass('resources/assets/sass/style.scss', 'public/css')
.version();
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: This will fix it. `mix.setPublicPath(path.resolve('./'))` it has nothing to do with the copy directory

Comment: @MichaelMano -hi, can you please guide me more regarding your answer? thank you in advance.

Comment: I can not explain why this fixed the issue for me sorry. Its happened to a lot of people and this is the way that fixes it and no one explains.

Comment: @MichaelMano - i mean, where would i put this? because i tried adding this and i still got an error. Hoping that you can make an answer entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below worked as expected now.

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix'),

mix.copyDirectory('node_modules/bootstrap', 'public/vendor/bootstrap')
.sass('resources/assets/sass/style.scss', 'public/css')
.version();
```

It turned out that the one of the `copyDirectory` entry is causing the problem, which is:

```
.copyDirectory('node_modules/chart.js', 'public/vendor/chart.js')
```

So, I just converted it to `.copy()` and I just copied the js and css file for the chart.js.

Everything worked as expected after that.

Answer (score 1):

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix'),

mix.setPublicPath(path.resolve('./'))
    .copyDirectory('node_modules/bootstrap', 'public/vendor/bootstrap')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/style.scss', 'public/css')
    .version();
```

This should resolve the issues, if not I am unsure on what it could be. maybe your mix manifest